# Is cancelling scan for lost files dangerous?

Tags: hard-drive, mac

Earlier I tried to recover some old files that I had deleted completely. I used the apps “EaseUS Data recover wizard” and “Diskdrill”. During the scan for lost files, I changed my mind and tried to cancel it. I was greeted with a warning message that recommended me not to do it, on both apps. And foolish as I am I ignored it!
The message said something about that some files might go lost. What I wonder is: What might have happened now that I cancelled the scan? Is there a risk that some files at my computer have taken damage, or been removed?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such scans are read-only and safe to cancel.

Biggest risk of trying such software is installing them on the same drive you're trying to recover files from as you run the risk of overwriting data you seek to recover.

Also, by doing scans using different tools to determine which is 'best' wastes time. Depending on the cause of the data loss an unstable drive may further deteriorate and if you're for example aiming to recover deleted files, every second you waste risks part of such files being overwritten.

But read-only scans in themselves do not delete data nor does cancelling a scan.

Comment: I was using it on the same drive that I was straying to recover files from: Is there any way to find out if something has gone wrong?

Comment: Not really unless you can compare against result of previous scan. But if the files were deleted from a system drive, time is against you. Also, if deleted from an SSD there pretty much zero chance to recover the file due to TRIM, I made a video demonstrating this: https://youtu.be/NyLQbxnPurc.

Comment: Right now I am not trying to recover any files, just trying to make sure that all is okay with my computer. Thanks for the video though!

Comment: Oh yes, the scans did not damage your computer, they just read just like data is read from the hard drive all the time. Consider accepting one of the answers given.

Comment: What happens with lost clusters in FAT32 and NTFS? Will they be saved as files without affection of the FAT or the cluster bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

Canceling a scan for lost files during data recovery should not damage or remove your existing files. However, incomplete or inaccurate recovery results may occur. It's advisable to have backups of important data to prevent data loss.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).